# How React listens for state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have started learning **React.js** and I wonder how React listens for state changes?

I mean I know there is not any event listeners in Javascript for tracking variable change and I'm pretty sure that we can not listen for changing a variable (without using an interval to check the change) in Javascript natively...

But in React if you change a property of a **state** it will finds out the change instantly?!

How it's implemented in React?

Comment: Have a read of something like https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_state.asp and let us know if you're still puzzled.. (And also if you're using redux, let us know)

Comment: *'>- no event listeners.. for tracking variables'* - not entirely true, there's such thing as [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: Such function like `setState` only update the state and call the component again with new state value. [Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) has a good explanation for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React does not passively listen for state changes at all. The only way it knows the state changed is because you explicitly tell react to change the state. In class components, that's done with `this.setState`:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: 'valentina';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ name: 'jebediah' });
    }, 1000);
  }

  // ...
}
```

In a function component, that's with the state-setter function returned by `useState`:

```
const Example = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('valentina');

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setName('jebediah');
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: But I thought we can use `this.state.name = 'some name';` too...!!!

Comment: React will not know that you did that and thus will not know to rerender. It's possible that some other piece of code might call setState and cause a rerender, and when that happens react will use `'some name'`. But if that happens, you just got lucky. Do not mutate the state in react; call setState.

Comment: Hi @Pixier hope you are getting fun with React
In state management just keep in mind that STATE VARIABLES ARE IMMUTABLES so you cant modify them directly by doing` this.state.name = 'Some state'`
Intead use `useState` React Hooks for functional component or  this.setState({state: value}) as showed by @NicholasTower